# Trigger to copy field to another

Tags: apex, trigger

Its not working. Actually I want to copy temporary address to permanent address field when the checkbox is active.

```
trigger copyAddress on Demo1__c (before insert) {
    for(Demo1__c dmo : [SELECT Temporary_Address__c FROM Demo1__c WHERE Id IN : Trigger.new]){

         if(dmo.Same_Address__c){
            //Same_Address__c is Checkbox type
            dmo.Permanent_Address__c = dmo.Temporary_Address__c ;
         }
       }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Workflow Rule` here. Don't use `Apex Trigger` except as a last resort.

Comment: ok... but for practice i am expecting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are making modifications in a before trigger, you need to loop through the context records, not re-query for them. Your query won't even return any results in a `before insert` trigger.

**Incorrect**

```
for (Demo1__c dmo : [/*query*/])
```

**Correct**

```
for (Demo1__c record : trigger.new)
```

---

That said, this sort of simple functionality should be accomplished declaratively. Take a look at **[Visual Development – When to Click Instead of Write Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/12/forcedotcom-declarative-development.html)**:

> [image: Tricycle]
>
> Instead of writing Triggers, we can automate Field Updates using Workflow – automatically populating a field with a default value or updating a field based on the value of another field is a pretty common requirement. Workflow can address the basic use cases just as well as writing an Apex Trigger.

Comment: When you are developing a live application, always try to use declarative functionality over code, if possible!

Comment: @VipulMittal So did it solve your question?

Comment: Man, I want one of those bikes!